# Django render() not passing variable to template?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

```
def get_queryset(self):
        ...
        #days = {day1 : [[FreetimeStart, FreetimeEnd], [[Meeting1Start, Meeting1End], ...]], ...}
        days = {}
        for i in range(len(compilation)):
            days[daylist[i]] = compilation[i]
        print(days)

        return render(self.request, 'calendar.html', {"days":days})
```

Above (with nonrelevant code omitted) is a function from a Django view I've been writing. It's *supposed* to send the days dictionary over to the template calendar.html (shown below), but it's not- I've confirmed via the print(days) statement that days is being generated properly and that the function is being called. I'm not getting any errors, either.

```
{{ days }}
<table>
    <tr>
        {% for key in days %}
            <th>
            {{ key }}
            </th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    <tr>
        {% for value in days.values %}
            <td>
            {% if value.0 %}
                Free time: {{ value.0.0 }} to {{ value.0.1 }}
            {% else %}
                Free time: None
            {% endif %}
            </td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>

    <tr>
        {% for value in days.values %}
            <td>
            {% for meeting in value.1 %}
                Meeting from {{ meeting.0 }} to {{ meeting.1 }}</br>
            {% endfor %}
            </td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>

</table>
```

What am I doing wrong here? There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with my render() arguments.

Comment: `get_queryset` should return a *queryset*, e.g. `MyModel.objects.all()`. It doesn't make sense to call `render()` there.

Comment: Ah, I see. So it should work if I were to, say, change get_queryset() to get()? Edit: Yep, confirmed. I was previously unaware that function names were this significant in class-based views.

Comment: Try to avoid overriding `get()` in class based views -  you can end up duplicating code or missing functionality of the parent class. In your case, perhaps you want to override [`get_context_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context) and add `days` to the context.